# How to get the images of a TDBNavigator with a TStyle theme applied to it?

Tags: delphi, themes, delphi-12-athens

I'm using Delphi 12 Athens, and have a custom style applied to my application.

I would like to get the images of a `TDBNavigator` to assign them to a specific `TSpeedButton`.

Is this possible?

I've try this, but the images returned are the defaults for the component:

```
ic  := TImageList.Create(self);
nav := THackDBNavigator.Create(self);
     
ic.Assign(THackDBNavigator( nav ).GetButtonImageList);
SpeedButtonFirst.Images     := ic;
SpeedButtonFirst.ImageIndex := Integer(nbFirst);
```

Comment: When a Style is applied to `TDBNavigator` component it does not replace the default images in its internal image list but instead overrides the rendering code which is then loading resources from Style instead of internal image list. So in order to show such images on your buttons you will have to modify the style to use those images on your speed buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to get the images from a style but you can use DrawElement:

```
var
  r: TRect;
begin
  FreeAndNil(SpeedButtonFirst.Glyph);
  SpeedButtonFirst.Glyph := TBitmap.Create(24, 24);
  r := Rect(0, 0, SpeedButtonFirst.Glyph.Width, 
    SpeedButtonFirst.Glyph.Height);
  TStyleManager.ActiveStyle.DrawElement(
    SpeedButtonFirst.Glyph.Canvas.Handle, 
    TStyleManager.ActiveStyle.GetElementDetails(tdnbFirstPressed), 
    r, r);
end;
```

Update: DrawElement is drawing already transparent. Check in unit Vcl.StyleAPI in method TSeBitmapObject.DrawNormal in line 5499 if DrawBitmap.Image.Transparent is set

Comment: I'll have to double check, but I'm pretty sure `Glyph := TBitmap.Create` is a memory leak. Property setters for images usually make a copy, you still have to free the original

Comment: This almost works.
The image created has a white background. Would it be possible to make it transparent?

Comment: @Lemy: Your point is (as always ;)) valid so I have added FreeAndNil before.